# Microsoft Graph - Can't read/write the calendar of other users

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I have a web app registered on Azure with the goal of being able to read and write the calendars of other users. To do so, I set [these permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0gHL.png) for this app on Azure.

However, when I try to, for example, create a new event for a given user, I get an error message. Here's what I'm using:

**Endpoint**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${requester}/calendar/events
```

**HTTP Header**

```
Content-Type    application/json
```

**Request Body**

```
{
  "subject": "${subject}",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "${remarks}"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "${startTime}",
    "timeZone": "${timezone}"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "${endTime}",
    "timeZone": "${timezone}"
  },
  "location": {
    "displayName": "${spaceName}",
    "locationEmailAddress": "${spaceEmail}"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "${spaceEmail}",
        "name": "${spaceName}"
      },
      "type": "resource"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error message**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "date": "2018-07-11T09:16:19"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

---

## Solution update

I managed to solve the problem by following the steps described in this link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: Can you please post what error message you do receive?

Comment: @KarlheinzReinhardt yeah sorry, totally forgot. Just updated the post.

Comment: Your request body looks ok. Maybe one of your injected values is wrong and causing this error, which would be weird as Graph would (normally) return a more exact response (e.g. wong time format,...). You could test your injected values in the [Graph-Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: I got this error:
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "DelegatedCalendarAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "date": "2018-07-11T12:37:54"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: did you obtain the token "on behalf of a user" or "without a user"? If you obtained the token on behalf of a user you can only read/write the calendar of this user.

Comment: some documentation about obtaining tokens [on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) and [without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

Comment: As you have `Application permission` (from screenshot) you need to make sure that you obtained token [without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) as KarlheinzReinhardt suggested. Use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to check if your token has the required role.

Comment: Thanks guys, managed to solve the issue thanks to your guidance. Cheers!

Comment: Btw @KarlheinzReinhardt, as it is the token I get is only valid for an hour. How can I get a token that is valid for longer, say years? So, in other words, how do I allow the app full access for a long time?

Comment: @robdy you too, please.

Comment: You just need to save the time when you obtained the token to variable and then check it and refresh your token accordingly. @KarlheinzReinhardt, lmk if you want to write an answer so OP can accept it (otherwise I can do it).

Comment: @robdy you can write the answer

Comment: @KarlheinzReinhardt, any chance of helping me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326521/microsoft-graph-error-when-subscribing-to-calendar-notifications

Comment: @robdy, you too please, if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326521/microsoft-graph-error-when-subscribing-to-calendar-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it's visible that you used application permission (although it'd be nice to include this information in your question):

[image]

Depending on kind of the permission you have given, you need to use proper flow to obtain access token ([on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) or [as a service](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). For application permissions you have to use flow for service, not on behalf of a user.

You can also check your token using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and make sure it's payload contains appropriate role. If it doesn't, it's very likely you used incorrect flow.

Regarding the expiration time of it, you may have found the information about refresh token ([for example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#refresh-the-access-token)). Keep in mind that it applies only to rights granted on behalf of a user. For access without a user you should make sure that you know when your token is going to expire and request a new one accordingly.

Comment: So @robdy, there is really no other option to extend the lifespan of the access token?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. Access tokens are not designed to be long-living passwords or something like that. That's pretty standard design.

Comment: So, for my goal here, I should have a way to refresh it every hour, or is there an alternative solution? Remember that I need for the app to be able to access everyone's calendar at all times

Comment: In function sending request to Graph add the step to check when was the last time of refreshing and if more than e.g. 55 mins ago, request new access token.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. But is that how these things are usually done? I'm fairly new to OAuth and all.

Comment: I don't feel competent enough to answer that question but in my experience - yes, that's how it's usually being done.