# Microsoft Graph - Error when subscribing to calendar notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I was trying to set up a subscription to the notifications of one of my calendars, but am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "date": "2018-07-13T13:32:37"
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the request is correct:

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://(...)/outlook/notifications",
   "resource": "me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2018-07-16T10:00:00.000Z",
   "clientState": "OutlookIntegration"
}
```

Any hint on what may be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess, it is not finding the calendar. Has it worked with other calendars? Is the access token a delegated token (there is user info inside it)?

Comment: @juunas no, it doesn't even work with the resource "me/events". However, in the Graph Explorer, it can find the specific calendar.

Comment: @juunas, the token is an application one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use /me with an application token.

Graph doesn't know what "me" is unless there is user info in the token.

You'll have to specify the user's object id or user principal name instead of "me". Like: `users/object-id-here`.

Comment: Wow, stupid me. That solved the issue, thanks a bunch @juunas!

Comment: Btw @juunas, any reason as to why each update in an event, for example, produces 3 rest calls to my endpoint?

Comment: No clue :/ That probably should not happen.

Comment: You need to return status code 202. Otherwise it will retry.